# Transitivité et intransitivité des verbes, une question de familiarité ?

Tags: verbes, transitivité, stylistique

Question pour les puristes du beau style uniquement.

Le verbe *corroborer* peut-il s'employer à la fois transitivement et intransitivement ? (d'une façon académique)

Je lis dans le dictionnaire qu'il est transitif, mais je l'entends et le vois écrit transitivement. « Je corrobore », comme on dirait « J'adhère »
familièrement, au lieu de corroborer un fait, etc.

Même question pour *adhérer*. Est-il transitif **et** intransitif ? Ou est-il acceptable intransitivement seulement en langage familier ? Quand j'entends ou lis « Je corrobore » pour dire « J'approuve », c’est comme s'il manquait quelque chose.

Je ne sais pas si ma question est claire, je la clarifierai à condition que vous la relisiez d'abord deux fois, avec une aspirine.

Comment: En rapport avec la transitivité et l'intransitivité des verbes qu'est-ce qui pourrait être ou ne pas être une question de familiarité?

Answer (score 1):

Contrib entièrement revue suite aux observations pertinentes de @Montéedelait en commentaires.

On considèrera donc que la question ne portait que sur l'usage de *corroborer* et non sur la transitivité des verbes en général comme le laissait suggérer le titre de la question.

Précisément donc :

1/ *corroborer* est un verbe qui peut admettre un Complément d'Objet Direct.

2/ Quel que soit le registre de la langue, il est **toujours** possible de faire l'élision d'un COD.

=> On peut donc *corroborer*... tout court. Et tout ceci n'ayant strictement rien à voir avec des notions **arbitraires** de transitivité.

De même, si je termine cette contribution par un *J'espère que tu as bien compris*, *comprendre n'aurait pas plus de valeur *intransitive* car cette phrase ne serait rien d'autre que *J'espère que tu as bien compris... ce que je viens d'écrire / cela* avec élision du COD pour cause d'évidence.

NDaCOSwt : Je ne prétends pas qualifier en regard de la condition mise en avant par l'auteur de la question.

Comment: J'ai compris que la question concernait surtout la valeur **intransitive** du verbe. Est-elle permise en langue académique, ou seulement dans le registre familier. La valeur transitive est acceptée d’emblée, puisque déclarée explicitement [dans le dictionnaire de l’Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/corroborer).

Comment: @Montéedelait : C'est toi qui a raison! Je me suis laissé emporté (à tort) par cette **@@!!** de **##!@@** de distinction *transitif* / *intransitif* qui, pour avoir 36 définitions (parfois contradictoires) ne possède aucun sens et, en tout cas, ne correspond à aucune réalité de la langue. Ou alors à sa seule dimension syntaxique. Il faudra un jour que je revienne sur l'histoire de cette distinction **arbitraire** que, d'ailleurs, la première édition du DA ne s'autorisait pas à faire. Mais merci pour ton observation, je vais changer la place du TL,DR! ;-)

Comment: @Montéedelait : Et pour répondre en court au point central de la question : Oui, puisqu'il n'est question ici que de syntaxe et donc... de présence ou non d'un COD, on peut **toujours** faire l'élision d'un COD. => Corroborer... tout court! (à noter que ce n'est pas cela qui donnera au verbe une valeur *intransitive*... ( comme quoi... le COD ne serait en plus pas déterminant dans la distinction... Harff! )

Comment: Et dans le comm plus haut, je me suis laissé emport**er**... évidemment... !

Comment: Il me semble que la transitivité ou intransitivité des verbes est une réalité qui déborde de la langue française et introduit une distinction admise par plusieurs langues. Par exemple [le russe](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) et [le finnois](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitiivisuus_(kielioppi)), pour s’éloigner un peu du français par l’alphabet dans le premier cas, et sortir carrément de l’hindo-européen dans le second.

Comment: @Montéedelait  : Hmmm... Je ne te suivrai pas sur cette *réalité*. La seule et unique réalité linguistique qui soit sur ce sujet (et effectivement commune à de nombreuses langues), c'est la **diathèse**  qui renvoie au rapport entretenu par la personne avec le procès verbal. De cette *diathèse* on classera d'abord (dès le latin) les verbes en 5 catégories. C'était trop, sans doute, il a fallu simplifier arbitrairement.

Comment: Il me semble que la distinction transitif/intransitif est un cadre valide, d’autant plus qu'il est celui précisément invoqué par l'auteur de la question. Je suis parfaitement d'accord que l'on puisse le considérer invalide pour certaines applications, voire pour toutes, mais ça me semble un peu déplacé dans le cas spécifique de cette question, parce que ce n'est clairement pas le but recherché, et qu'une réponse demeure possible même si le cadre de réflexion est hypothétiquement incomplet ou imparfait.

Comment: @Montéedelait : +1 pour ton dernier comm!... Je réalise m'être vautré dans un hors sujet. (Tu aurais peut-être dû **commencer** par cette critique... ;-) ) Merci tout de même, je revois ma copie.

Comment: Mes plus plates excuses. Je ne lis pas dans les pensées et ne me doutais guère qu'ainsi dévierait la discussion.

Comment: @Montéedelait : Je t'en prie.

Answer (score 1):

À défaut de parler de l'usage intransitif des verbes en question, on note la possibilité de leur *emploi absolu* ou en *construction absolue* et on présente ces exemples pour [corroborer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corroborer) et [adhérer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/adh%C3%A9rer) au TLFi :

> La môme, de son coin à droite, corroborant. − Oui!... oui!
>   (Feydeau)
>   16. ... C'est alors qu'une Isolde ou qu'une Phèdre tiennent les propos à la fois les plus désordonnés et les plus impérieux qu'une gravité,
>   qu'une dignité aussi, les ceignent, adhèrent, collent à elles comme la
>   plus inaliénable draperie. (Ch. Du Bos)
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé, à corroborer (« empl.
>   abs. ou en const. abs. ») et adhérer (« Noter l'emploi abs. dans l'ex.
>   16. ») ]

En suivant cette piste, on lit que :

> Un mot est construit **absolument** quand le complément ou la suite qu'il
>   appelle d'ordinaire ne sont pas exprimés, soit que cette indication
>   soit jugée inutile, soit qu'elle ait déjà été donnée (ce qui
>   s'apparente à l'ellipse) : *Nous mangeons à cinq heures* (peu importe ce
>   que nous mangeons).
>   [...]
>   La construction absolue ne se réalise pas ou se réalise rarement pour
>   certains verbes : *avoir, posséder, battre, comporter, concerne,
>   contenir, détester, entourer, déchirer, ébranler, rencontrer,
>   persécuter, alléguer, féliciter, redouter ; appartenir, raffoler,
>   attenter ; provenir, habiter*, etc. Pour d'autres au contraire elle
>   est très fréquente : *fumer (défense de fumer), lire, coudre,
>   tricoter*, etc. L'emploi absolu peut être du à l'euphémisme : *faire*
>   et *aller* pour « déféquer ».  Parmi les emplois absolus venus à la
>   mode à la fin du XXe s. dans une langue très familière, on cite
>   souvent *Ça craint* « il y a du danger » et *assurer* « être à la
>   hauteur de la situation » [...]
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, para. 1: §274, para 2: §276 a) ]

On peut donc avoir un emploi absolu pour un verbe transitif où le complément n'est pas exprimé.

Comment: **J**'aurais pour ma part bien du mal à répondre à une telle question car... l'*intransitivité*... je ne sais pas ce que c'est que cela. J'ai au demeurant l'impression que les grammaires pataugent dans la même choucroute que moi dans l'incapacité qu'elles sont à proposer un critère discriminant. Quand un truc est arbitraire, la différence entre ce truc et le reste est : ? Arbitraire! L'*intransitivité* ? FTS! (Enfin, ceci est mon opinion)

Comment: @aCOSwt D'accord, peut-on svp poser la question où une réponse expliquerait la différence entre l'usage intransitif et l'emploi absolu d'un verbe ? Je ne sais pas s'il y a un critère déterminant, on peut aborder ça sous des angles différents et parler de la nature des verbes et d'autre part de l'usage etc. Si vous pensez que c'est arbitraire vous pourriez le répondre. Je note a priori que l'emploi absolu ne vise pas que les verbes. Merci !