# L'emploi absolu d'un verbe et le verbe intransitif : perspectives ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, verbes, origine-ou-raison, transitivité

Dans une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32217) on se demande si certains verbes normalement transitifs peuvent s'employer correctement de manière *absolue* sans leur complément usuel (comme par ellipse). Au lexique on a fait état de ces emplois pour des verbes comme [corroborer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/corroborer) ou [adhérer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/adh%C3%A9rer).

Même si l'emploi absolu ou en construction absolue dépasse le cadre des seuls verbes et vise d'autres types de mots (noms etc.), on peut [se demander](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32217/transitivit%C3%A9-et-intransitivit%C3%A9-des-verbes-une-question-de-familiarit%C3%A9#comment66198_32268) en quoi consiste exactement la différence entre un l'emploi [intransitif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intransitif) d'un verbe et l'emploi d'un autre qui est généralement transitif mais qui serait employé de manière absolue : et si un usage absolu prépondérant changerait la transitivité d'un verbe ? Peut-on dire qu'il est plus utile de savoir qu'un verbe est transitif direct ou indirect que de savoir qu'il est transitif ou intransitif ? Peut-on rappeler l'origine de la [transitivité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivit%C3%A9_(grammaire)) d'un verbe, est-ce fondamental ou à l'usage, s'agit-il strictement d'une question de grammaire alors que l'emploi absolu d'un verbe ne serait quant à lui qu'une particularité de l'emploi ? Le complément n'appartient-il qu'à la phrase et le verbe, qu'au discours ?

Comment: Il y a différentes manières d'articuler et de présenter une réponse et l'exercice est utile à mon avis. Merci !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faute de temps pour rédiger toute la réponse à cette question, cette contribution sera rédigée en plusieurs fois.

**A/ LE PROBLÈME DES CATÉGORIES EN GÉNÉRAL**

*Transitif, absolu, verbe...* tous ces termes se rapportent à des **catégories** de la langue.
Catégoriser a un résultat satisfaisant et profitable lorsque l'objet de la catégorisation est rigoureusement rationn(el/alisable) ET discret(isable). Lorsque l'objet ne présente pas ces caractéristiques (et tel est bien le cas avec la langue) la catégorisation présente nécessairement des défauts :

- Le nombre de catégories, leurs étiquettes, les prédicats associés sont décidés **arbitrairement**.
- Si le système peut représenter un modèle grosso-modo acceptable de l'objet à un instant donné, avec des problèmes aux marges, il ne peut résister à son évolution et encore moins à son enrichissement, deux caractéristiques fondamentales d'une langue vivante, car c'est justement à la marge que la langue s'enrichit et se développe.

Pour réaliser ces problèmes liés à la catégorisation, il suffit... de considérer les couleurs de l'arc en ciel ou les notes de musique.

D'où une conclusion de cette première partie : tu avais fait un tiroir pour tes chaussettes blanches et un pour tes chaussettes noires, où dois-tu mettre tes chaussettes grises ? Bhein... où tu veux, de toute manière ton choix de classement était arbitraire et il ne correspond manifestement plus aux qualités de tes stocks.
Problématique que l'on peut tourner autrement pour plus de rapport avec ta question : Tu trouves une chaussette grise dans tes stocks : Est-elle noire ou est-elle blanche ?

<sub>Nota : Les problèmes liés à la catégorisation ne se limitent pas à cela. Il en est des plus graves mais de nature plus philosophique. Il existe une quantité impressionnante d'articles de recherche sur les problèmes liés à la catégorisation en linguistique, je laisse le lecteur curieux les chercher sur internet et me limite à la citation du premier à les avoir identifiés : Émile Benveniste in [*Problèmes de linguistique générale*](http://lecomte.al.free.fr/ressources/PARIS8_LSL/benveniste.pdf).</sub>

**B/ C'EST DE LA SYNTAXE OU DE LA SÉMANTIQUE ? LES DEUX MON GÉNÉRAL !**

En admettant que ces catégories représentent une réalité linguistique, la transitivité, l'emploi absolu, le verbe... représentent des **qualités syntaxico-sémantiques**.

Si, ici et maintenant, *je te demande si tu comprends* :

- il est une évidence que je n'utilise pas le verbe comprendre absolument, il est une évidence que je te demande si tu comprends **cela / ce que je viens d'expliquer** J'ai simplement fait l'élision du COD pour des raisons d'évidences. Sémantiquement, le COD, il existe de plein droit! Il est juste sous-entendu d'où : Pas d'emploi absolu après analyse sémantique.
- maintenant si tu extrais cette question de son contexte et présentes la phrase seule alors... tu n'as pour support décisionnel que la syntaxe. De laquelle tu pourrais effectivement déduire des qualités proches de l'emploi intransitif ou de l'emploi absolu... MAIS, tu ne peux en décider. La décision est rigoureusement impossible car tu ne peux juger QUE sur le plan syntaxique alors que la qualité est d'ordre syntaxico-sémantique.

En conclusion de cette partie : l'usage est absolu ? intransitif ? Si je n'ai qu'un bout de phrase pour en juger... je ne sais pas dire. Le premier malentendu sur ces sujets vient de là et du fait que la grammaire enseignée à l'école donne le primat à l'analyse syntaxique.

<sub>Nota : Sur un développement quant à la qualité syntaxico-sémantique de ces *machins-là*, on pourra lire, entre autres [le mémoire de Véronique Fortin](https://archipel.uqam.ca/5870/1/M13181.pdf).</sub>

**C/ Petite HISTOIRE DES CATÉGORIES VERBALES**

*petite* car on ne va tout de même pas remonter jusqu'à l’œuf non plus hein... 
la grammaire... c'est marrant... mais... pas plus de 5 minutes... ;-)

Les rapports syntaxiques et sémantiques (ainsi que la nécessité de les marquer) entre les constituants nominaux d'une phrase simple apparaissent très tôt. C'est, je crois, Apollonius Dyscole (II<sup>e</sup> siècle) qui se prend le premier à étendre cette nécessité au verbe.

Ainsi la *diathèse* (disposition) sera-t-elle déterminante pour trois des cinq classes de verbes que comptaient les grammaires latines de l'antiquité :

- Actif (disposant)
- Passif (disposé)
- Absolu (Neutre)

Les deux autres ? (Commun, Déponent)... Ha bha... who cares ? Elles seront abandonnées par les grammairiens latins du... XVI<sup>e</sup> qui fourgueront leurs éléments dans une des trois classes ci-dessus **sur la base de leur emploi en construction!!!** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sub>(1) Au XVI<sup>e</sup> le latin est déjà une langue morte... ce genre de manipe sur un corpus donc fini... trop facile!, même moi je sais faire!</sub>

**-> ~ mid XVII<sup>e</sup>**

Prudentes, Les premières grammaires françaises choisissent de ne pas changer une équipe qui gagne et reprennent ces trois catégories mais... la poule ne va pas rouler toute seule... ;-) :

Dans la tradition latine, Il faut la réunion de plusieurs critères pour déclarer un verbe *actif*

- Un critère morphologique (désinence en -o),
- Un critère sémantique (sémantisme
  de l‘action opposé à celui de la passion),
- Un critère syntaxique (**transition de l‘acte**<sup>(1)</sup>, construction avec l‘accusatif, le génitif ou le datif, et production du passif)

<sub>Nota (1) : On observera la présence de la *transitivité* mais entendue en tant que critère syntaxique.</sub>

Si la réunion de ces trois critères autorisait une classification des verbes latins sans ambigüité, ni contradiction, le français lui connaît des verbes de sens actif qui se construisent sans complément ou avec une préposition, des verbes de sens passifs qui se admettent la complémentation, des désinences sans rapport avec la choucroute... Bref... ce n'est plus du tout la même limonade.

Que je te m'aurais fait péter tout ce boxif, oui! Bhein non! Pour le seul profit du système, on va diminuer les contradictions en faisant péter un critère (le morphologique passe ainsi à la trappe), tripatouiller les deux autres pour que ça rentre et ce qui rentre toujours pas bhein... Au neutre!

La *grammaire de Port-Royal*<sup>(2)</sup> constitue dans cette histoire un jalon à double titre :

- D'abord parce l'édition de 1660 représente le bilan des travaux passés conclus par une définition de l'actif comme cumul de la propriété sémantique de l'action et réalisant la **propriété syntaxique de *transitivité*** entendue comme transition de l‘action entre deux entités représentant deux personnes différentes.
- Et ensuite du fait que l'édition de 1664, pour, dans un paragraphe malheureux, faire de *transitif* le synonyme d'*actif* va te me foutre un de ces pataquès d'ambivalence <sup>(1)</sup> et te me propulser tout ça dans une confusion dramatique.

<sub>(1) v.g. Par transitif, on devra entendre quoi ? La catégorie des verbes actifs ou la propriété syntaxique de transitivité ou... s'imaginer que la catégorie des verbes actifs se limite à ceux remplissant la seule propriété syntaxique de transitivité ?</sub>

<sub>(2) Nota : Je n'ai pas trouvé d'accès libre aux éditions que je mentionne. La plus tôtive disponible étant celle de 1676. Je propose donc [ce lien](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ezX8MVKpe7QC&pg=PR12&dq=grammaire%20de%20port%20royal&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiay5n3usXeAhVJxoUKHSlYA3gQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=grammaire%20de%20port%20royal&f=false) qui offre en plus le mérite d'une présentation par Jean-Marc Mandosio, espérant qu'elle répondra à la demande d'informations générales formulée en commentaires.</sub>

**-> mid XVII<sup>e</sup> -> mid XVIII<sup>e</sup>**

Regnier-Desmarais est le premier à remettre en question le classement des verbes fondé sur la notion de *disposition* et les auteurs de *Grammaires générales* vont lui embrayer le pas.

Les critères sémantiques disparaissent ou passent au second plan derrière un critère syntaxique qui ne porte très souvent même plus le nom de *transitivité* puisque c'est le **régime** (le complément du verbe) qui en déterminera la catégorie. On distingue alors :

- Le régime appelé *absolu*<sup>(1)</sup> ou *direct* ou encore *immédiat* (selon le grammairien) qui correspond grosso-modo à *notre* COD
- Le régime appelé *réflexif* ou encore *indirect* qui correspond grosso-modo à *notre* COI ou complément d'attribution.

<sub>nota (1) : Et bingo! au passage encore une ambivalence pour *absolu*.</sub>

**Et c'est ainsi la présence d'un régime direct qui devient le critère de classement du verbe dans la classe des actifs.**

C'est dingue ça non ? Sans dec ! Vous visez le virage ? La catégorisation du verbe ne dépend pas de caractéristiques propres au verbe mais de ce qu'il y a autour ??? Non! Mhé! Vous ne rangez plus vos chaussettes dans vos tiroirs en fonction de leur couleur, hauteur, épaisseur... mais... en fonction des chaussures que vous mettrez autour, vos chemises en fonction de la cravate !!!

On s'imagine aussi la victime collatérale de cette affaire, la catégorie des verbes neutres qui passe de poubelle à décharge publique. Au point que certains (Wailly) proposeront un tri selectif... en lui créant trois sous-catégories :

- Actif Indirect
- Actif Intransitif
- Neutre! (lol)

**-> mid XVIII<sup>e</sup> -> mid XIX<sup>e</sup>**

On ne peut tout classer dans la même armoire ? Qu'à cela ne tienne, on va en faire deux!

Beauzée arrive avec au moins la conscience de la réalité que les critères ne peuvent être exclusivement syntaxiques mais aussi que, comme on l'a vu plus haut, ajouter un critère sémantique conduit à une impasse. D'où son idée originale de deux classements.

- Le premier qui regroupe les catégories ACTIF, PASSIF, NEUTRE et fondée la signification lexicale du verbe.
- Le second qui regroupe les catégories RELATIF et ABSOLU fondée sur la construction du verbe, avec ou sans complément *"objectif"* (COD ou COI).

Thurot, De Sacy embrayent grosso-modo le pas, changeant toutefois la terminologie et en finassant un peu.
C'est ainsi que le *maudit* *transitif* va réapparaitre en place du *relatif* de Beauzée, ainsi que son antonyme *intransitif* <sup>(1)</sup>

<sub>(1) mais... Attention... associés à la présence d'un COD pour l'un et d'un COI pour l'autre...
Autrement dit... ce que certains appellent aujourd'hui innocemment *verbe transitif indirect* etait, à cette époque, non moins innocemment appelé *verbe intransitif*...</sub>

Serreau, Boussi, Vannier... c'est bon! Le train de la double classif est pris... chacun s'employant à laisser sa patte sur le plan de la terminologie... <sup>(1)</sup>

<sub>(1) Parler de *foisonnement* terminologique est faible. Visez plutôt... *complément immédiat, verbe oblique!* Ha génial ça oblique comme étiquette... Vous voulez que je vous en touche un mot, là maintenant ? Non ? C'est sûr ?... ;-) OK, une autre fois alors.</sub>

... À SUIVRE...

Nota général : les études savantes sur le sujet sont nombreuses. J'ai limité mes références aux sources d'accès libre et gratuit. D'autres sources pourraient, et à raison, être considérées plus pertinentes ou de meilleure qualité, n'hésitez pas à les souligner en commentaires.

Comment: Pb : Comment rédiger dans une fonte de taille différente de la standard par défaut ?

Comment: Les possibilités sont limitées, j'ai mis des exemples à la fin de ton post. Enlève-les une fois que tu les auras vus !

Comment: Grand merci à toi. C'est mieux avec les notes. Je réalise ce faisant à la lecture de ton hr, sub... qu'il s'agit de codes HTML, l'éditeur de réponse interprète-t-il correctement le HTML ?

Comment: C'est très limité : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme : Typo corrigée. Pour le lien vers de l'info générale de qualité sur la GPR, je cherche mais... c'est pas simple. Pour le reste... vous comprendrez à la fin de mon exposé le pourquoi de l'absence de liens vers des éclairages simplifiés. Enfin, si vous n'avez pas l'expertise pour évaluer mes propos,.. ne vous en souciez pas car... je n'ai, pour ma part, pas nécessairement **toute** l'expertise requise... pour l'écrire. En particulier... pas celle qu'autoriserait une absence de parti pris dans l'affaire. Mais... comme vous aurez pu le lire... je ne le dissimule pas.

Comment: Merci, je salue votre effort de recherche et la présentation de matériel original de gens qui réfléchissent aussi à certains de ces sujets-là. À suivre !