# In French, can an intransitive verb have an indirect objects

Tags: grammaire

The notes for the DuoLingo French course claim that an intransitive verb, in French, can take an indirect object:

[image]

In "Je parle à Jacques", is "parler" an intransitive verb, and "à Jacques" indirect object (introduced by à) ?

Comment: These sound like they're confusing the English definitions of *transitive* and *intransitive*, with the French ones.

Comment: @PeterShor, can you eleborate, perhaps in an answer? What are the differences between the English definitions of those two words, vs the French definitions?

Comment: In English, one definition of an *intransitive verb* is one that cannot take a direct object. See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transitive_verb). In French, a verb can be transitive but only take indirect objects. See [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/verbe_transitif). So when Duolingo says that intransitive verbs can have indirect objects (jlliagre points out that this is a contradiction) they seem to be confusing the French and English definitions of transitive verbs.

Comment: I think the different definitions come out of the way the languages work, and that these definitions make sense for their respective languages. So it's not clear to me that it makes sense to teach French to English speakers using the English definition of *transitive verb*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duolingo's last statement is self-contradictory. By definition, intransitive verbs can't have *compléments d'objets*.

The confusion might be due to the fact many verbs can be used either  in a transitive or an intransitive way. Transitivity is more about defining their usage than some intrinsic quality of a verb. Only a subset of verbs are exclusively of one kind or another, e.g. *dormir* is exclusively intransitive.

On the other hand, *[parler](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parler)* can be used either as an intransitive, transitive direct or transitive indirect verb.

See also [this reply](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32320/1109).