# Un emploi du verbe « dire » (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: emploi-absolu

> À cet homme de sens pondéré et rassis, le détraquement cérébral de
> Letondu apparaissait prodigieusement farce et cocasse. Il étouffa dans le
> creux de sa main un rire qui s’y acheva en foirade, car le chef, d’un geste
> bref, venait de lui imposer silence :
> — Chut !… Écoutez !
> — Que d’hommes ! — je dis : en cette maison (déclamait maintenant Letondu, avec une majesté imposante), que d’hommes justement accusés de servilité et de bassesse seraient ici soupçonnés du contraire ! si ce contraire n’était encore un moyen détourné, qui les signale…
> (Ici, ce fut le bruit d’une chaise qu’on a empoignée au dossier,
> brutalement replantée, ensuite, sur le sol.)
> — … à la réprobation générale !
> Il dit, et, de nouveau, se tut. Les deux hommes écoutaient toujours, dans
> l’attente anxieuse de ce qui se préparait.

Le verbe « dire » est un verbe transitif;  on  mentionne bien la possibilité d'un emploi absolu au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dire), mais cet emploi ne correspond pas.

Est-ce que  « il dit » serait une rare occurrence d'emploi absolu, et alors le sens serait « il dit (encore) quelque chose » ? Serait-ce plutôt le cas que « il dit » réfère à « … à la réprobation générale ! » comme dans « — … à la réprobation générale !, dit-il » ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147240/discussion-on-question-by-lph-un-emploi-du-verbe--dire--messieurs-les-ronds-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Ce *il dit* se rapporte à toute la tirade du protagoniste qui commence avec *je dis* et qui le précède, et il est utilisé pour ponctuer la fin de cette tirade.

La structure est: *je dis* ... tirade de Letondu ... *il dit et se tut*. Avec ce *il dit, se tut*, Courteline reprend le contrôle de la narration, indique que la tirade est finie et décrit la scène qui vient immédiatement après, où les deux hommes attendent anxieusement la suite

Le TLFi mentionne cet usage possible du verbe *dire* (en "absolu" = verbe transitif utilisé sans complément) pour "ponctuer la fin d'une déclaration" (qui est ici encore plus clair puisque le *il dit* de Courteline fait écho au *je dis* de Letondu) [TLFi, II.C.3](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dire) (merci @None):

> [Dire ponctue la fin d'une déclaration] J'ai dit! Puisse notre union durer autant que la terre et le soleil! j'ai dit (Chateaub., Natchez,1826, p. 196); cf. aussi p. 424).

Courteline semble utiliser des phrases "saccadées" et le texte comprend des incises et des indications de l'auteur qui viennent interrompre son flot si bien qu'on a une impression tout à la fois d'un style vivant, et d'un style à mi-chemin entre la prose et le théâtre.

Merci @None encore une fois pour avoir signalé que ce *il dit* fait écho au *je dis* utilisé au début de la tirade de Letondu, et pour avoir signalé aussi la validité de l'emploi absolu du verbe *dire*.

Comment: Assez convainquant … ça me semble être la meilleure possibilité.

Comment: Bof comme réponse, il est quand même insinué dans la question que dire n'aurait pas d'emploi absolu ce que ne dément pas  ta réponse (ça existe, voir TLF). *Il dit* (il finit de parler)

Comment: @None Je n'ai pas réagi sur l'emploi absolu, tu as raison. Je vais ajouter.

Comment: Pour moi - mais on entre dans le subjectif - ce "il dit" fait écho au *je dis :* d'un peu plus haut. Courteline travaillait-il son style ? Je ne sais pas, il cherchait à faire des effets, c'est sûr. Et on peut reprendre quelqu'un qui termine son "discours"  par "j'ai dit" avec un "tu as dit" (et tous les sous-entendus que ça comporte, ça peut avoir quelque chose de méprisant)

Comment: @None - encore une excellente remarque! En fait, tu as complètement raison, l'echo avec _je dis_ est assez flagrant.

Comment: Tu joues au bridge ? : *À vous de dire.*  C'est un emploi absolu du verbe aussi.  Le TLF donne aussi *N'avoir qu'(un mot) à dire* en emploi absolu. Et dans l'expression *histoire de dire* aussi il me semble que ça en est un, même si ce sont des emplois différents de la question. Voir aussi l'exemple du wiktionnaire (dire, intransitif). Et [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32320/358) *je ne sais pas dire*.  Mais pour en revenir à la question, citons ce que des parents excédés ont dit à leurs enfants insistants : « J'ai dit, ça suffit maintenant tu me fiches la paix. ».

Comment: @None Oui j'ai remarqué que le TLF donne plusieurs exemples d'emploi "absolu". "Absolu" est-il le terme correct? J'aurais simplement dit "sans complément".

Comment: TLF absolu, D1b. [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/lexies/emploi%20absolu).

Comment: @None - merci! Je ne connaissais pas.